# Within Maven : how to display detailed SureFire test results (convert from xml to html)?

Tags: maven, pmd, maven-surefire-plugin

How to get Maven/SureFire to produce an HTML test reports instead of the XML one?
for SureFire, PMD and the rest of the Quality Control tools.

So it would look like the ones [here](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/project-reports.html).

Comment: I think the usage docs can point you in the right direction - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html. Or is there some other issue you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks Nick, is there a universal Maven plugin that transforms XML reports (from other plugins) into HTML? the link in the original post shows all reports in HTML, that is PMD, Sonar, CheckStyle FindBugs

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I entirely understand what you are after. Are you looking for a single plugin that will convert any old xml report into html? Including reports (code coverage, for example) that may not be supported by the surefire report plugin?

Comment: yeah, exactly, something like that

Comment: So as I understand it, the surefire report plugin will only present what it lists in the project reports link you listed, but not "any" xml report you throw at it. But I think that plugin will get you what you need, unless there's a specific type of report you would like support for.

Comment: I will work with this for now, thanks. I will accept your suggestion if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on our conversation above, it sounds like you are looking for an all in one XML -> HTML converted. I don't know of a plugin like that, but I believe the surefire report plugin combined with one or two others will get you where you need to be.

For starters, I would check out the [usage docs for the surefire-report plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire-archives/surefire-2.17/maven-surefire-report-plugin/usage.html). Additionally I threw together a quick example of how you can get started by combining the surefire, pmd, and surefire report plugin:

Using the following project structure:

```
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── Main.java
    │   │   └── SomeClass.java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        └── java
            └── SampleTest.java
```

And these class definitions:

SomeClass.java

```
import java.util.List; //Unused import, so PMD will have something to pick up

public class SomeClass {

    public void testMethod(){
        System.out.println("This is my test method with some PMD violations");
    }
}
```

SampleTest.java

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

//Sample tests, so the surefire report will have something to show
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
}
```

and finally, pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>plugins</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

The result is that when I run

```
mvn clean pmd:pmd site
```

I can then open up the site that was generated:

```
open target/site/index.html
```

From there, I can see my generated reports, in my case, just PMD and surefire test reports:
[image: Landing]

[image: PMD]

Additionally, if you want to get more reports that maybe the surefire reporting plugin doesn't help with, check out [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), and maybe even take a look into Sonar.

Comment: Thanks Nick, a very detailed and elegant answer